# Regex, getting end of server address

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Can't figure out why this doesn't work. I need to capture just the server address (before the / or ?, whichever comes first) and then anything left over in another capture group. So:

http://something.com/path?query=hello/goodbye

becomes

```
g1:  http://
g2:  something.com
g3:  /path?query=hello/goodbye
```

But every regex I try, the server address capture group includes the slash, these:

```
/(https?:\/\/)(.+)([\/\?].+)/
/(https?:\/\/)(.+)(\/|\?.+)/
```

Give me:

```
g1:  http://
g2:  something.com/path
g3:  ?query=hello/goodbye
```

I have even tried saying 'not slash', or so I thought, but it didn't work:

```
/(https?:\/\/)([.^\/]+)(\/|\?.+)/
```

Comment: You have a wayward dot in `[.^\/]` - remove that dot, or simpler use `[\w.]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx [`(https?:\/\/)([^\/?]*)(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Iy7D56/2)

- `(https?:\/\/)` matches `http://` or `https://`
- `([^\/?]*)` matches anything until a `/` or a `?`
- `(.*)` matches what's left

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/Iy7D56/2)

Answer (score 0):

For your regex `(https?:\/\/)(.+?)([\/\?].+)`  you are almost there.

You could make the `(.*)` part [non greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html): `(.*?)` to match the server address.

[`(https?:\/\/)(.+?)([\/\?].+)`](https://regex101.com/r/YGFtEW/1)

Note that you use 3 capturing groups but according to your question you only want to capture the server address and anything left over in another capture group. You could start you regex with a non capturing group `(?:` to get only 2 groups.